# Google Classroom: Does "not a Google Apps user" go away?

Tags: google-classroom

With the March, 2017 announcement that

> Classroom is now available for users with personal Google accounts, such as homeschoolers, tutoring programs, lifelong learners, and others who aren’t associated with a school.

Are there any conditions that can result in the Java API returning a `GoogleJsonResponseException` where `getDetails().getMessage()` contains the text "*The user is not a Google Apps user*"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this part of the [Google Classroom API documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors), specifically for `NotGoogleAppsUser`:

> **NotGoogleAppsUser**
>
> `NotGoogleAppsUser` indicates that the requesting user does not belong to a G Suite domain.
>
> *Possible Action*: Prompt the user to re-authenticate using a "G Suite for Education" account. Provide a link to [using multiple accounts](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977) so the user can select the correct account.

Comment: Yes, I believe that the returned message text starts with @NotGoogleAppsUser. But I'm failing to understand if we will ever see it again. For instance: At the beginning of March, if I attempted to get the "me" user profile from my personal Google account, I would see that exception. After the above announcement, I do not see that exception from my personal Google account - presumably because all personal accounts now belong to some G Suite domain.  If that's the case, will the Google API ever throw that exception? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing explicitly mentioned in the docs on what is happening *behind the scenes* during the checking of the user's account type. However, basing from your testing ("*I do not see that exception from my personal Google account*"), it is presumable that Personal Google accounts are added to a G Suite domain. In that case, it is *probable* that this exception might no longer thrown. Unless Google changes what triggers this exception and updates the documentation, or a Googler decides to answer here, there is no way to clearly know. But your test result is proving the current behavior.